# Run node.js twice using sh script

Tags: node.js, bash

I created a bash script named `runall.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
node ../app1/app.js && node ../app/app.js
```

I `chmod +x ./runall.sh` and can run it.

But only `../app1/app.js` gets started.
If I run `node ../app2/app.js` manually it works.

Comment: what if you say `node ../app1/app.js && echo "hello"`? Do you get a "hello" back?

Comment: No. I just tried that.

Comment: Do you want to run them both at once, or wait for the first to exit before running the second?

Comment: Then this means that the first command is not being executed properly. `command1 && command2` runs `command1` and, in case this was done successfully, then runs `command2`.

Comment: BTW, if this is for running background services, the approach you should be taking is completely different (setting up a separate service for each).

Comment: I want to start them and kill them later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to background with &?

```
#!/bin/bash
node ../app1/app.js &; node ../app/app.js &
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator in shell scripting tries to do a short-circuit `AND` comparison. That means that it checks to see what the result of the first command is before the second command starts. So it will wait until the first call to `node` terminates before calling the second one.

Answer (score 0):

As @daniel said before, the command after the '&&' operator will only be called, after the first command returned from execution.

So you could send a command to the background with the '&' operator or you could probably use some sort of node.js process manager like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

That way your **runall.sh** could look like

```
#! /bin/bash
forever start ../app1/app.js
forever start ../app2/app.js
```